# Sumif index and match & Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula

I have a bit of a dilemma with the Countif Index and Match function when used for multiple tables. (on Google Sheets)
Basically what I want to do is the following:

I use a simple table as an example - I want to count the sum total of values with similar descriptions (Like A, B etc) over different tables.
If I use "`=SUMIF($D$2:D$10,"A",Index($D$2:$E$10,Match("A",$D$2:$D$10,0),2))`" for A where the Match is used for the [row], A gives a correct answer, but B, C etc is incorrect.

On the other hand, when I use "`=SUMIF($D$2:D$10,"B",Index($D$2:$E$10,0,Match("B",$D$2:$D$10,0)))`" where the Match is used for [column], B is correct but everything else is wrong.

I'm not sure where my mistake is and why I cant get the formula to work for all variables? And then across all tables too.
Please assist :D
[image]

Comment: IMO quite an interesting question which reveals some interesting behaviour of SUMIF - pity it has been marked down.

Answer (score 0):

The following formula

```
=SUMIF($D$2:D$10,"A",Index($D$2:$E$10,Match("A",$D$2:$D$10,0),2))
```

resolves to

```
=SUMIF($D$2:D$10,"A",Index($D$2:$E$10,1,2))
```

which in turn resolves to

```
=SUMIF($D$2:D$10,"A",$E$2)
```

But the documentation both for Google sheets and Excel says that SUMIF must be called as follows

```
SUMIF(range, criterion, [sum_range])
```

So what happens if [sum_range] is just a cell reference like $E$2, and not a range? The answer is that it is expanded to match the criteria range so what you get is:

```
=SUMIF($D$2:D$10,"A",$E$2:E$10)
```

This works perfectly and you get the sum of the rows in column E where column D contains "A".

But what happens if you have

```
=SUMIF($D$2:D$10,"B",Index($D$2:$E$10,Match("B",$D$2:$D$10,0),2))
```

This resolves to

```
=SUMIF($D$2:D$10,"B",$E$3)
```

So what you now get is

```
=SUMIF($D$2:D$10,"B",$E$3:$E$11)
```

which looks like this

[image]

with the net result that you get the rows in E3:E10 corresponding to the ones in column D which contain a B. These are the 2nd and 4th rows, which contain 20 and 30, giving you a total of 50.

The answer to the second part of the question is that anything other than B in the formula

```
=SUMIF($D$2:D$10,"B",Index($D$2:$E$10,0,Match("B",$D$2:$D$10,0)))
```

will not give you the second column of D2:E10, so it will fail.

Comment: I did say 'as far as I can see'...obviously that isn't very far.

Comment: Thank you so much! The origin of the problem is now clear so I can see why it gave unexpected/ strange results.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you use a query instead! =query(D:E,"select D,sum(E) group by D") should work. And then you wouldn't need separate formulas for each question.

Comment: Thanks so much @ Tom Sharpe, your input gave some quality insight into why the formulae gave the results it did & based on your analysis I was able to get the correct results!!